# japaneese characters are not displaying when parsing with apache TIKA

Tags: java, apache-tika

I use following code to extract some japanese text from a PDF but out put file does not contain japaneese characters , instead of that there are some junk characters . Please help me to display exact japanese characters.

```
    InputStream is = null;
try {
  is = new FileInputStream("D:/jpn.pdf");
  ContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler();
  Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
  PDFParser pdfparser = new PDFParser();
  pdfparser.parse(is, contenthandler, metadata, new ParseContext());
  System.out.println(contenthandler.toString());
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

current out put : (?\3Ï? ä=>Yc? ³?;2+?Y/èN?)#/SM]TZ

?#U?{?6xM?1zT[Nmù6?K??(Ñ

Comment: Have you made sure that your console is correctly configured for UTF8 output, and with suitable fonts?

Comment: How should I check that ? Any idea

Comment: I changed console to UTF-8 but issue still there

Comment: I've just googled for "Sample Japanese PDF", and tried parsing that with Tika and it failed too. Probably best to [report a bug in the Apache Tika issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA) and upload a small sample file that shows the problem